# Understanding the proof if $f$ is continuous on $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $K \subseteq A$ is compact then $f(K)$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, compactness

I am trying to understand the proof of if $f$ is continuous on $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $K \subseteq A$ is compact $\implies$ $f(K)$ is compact. This is the proof:[image]

**Can someone please explain how $f(x) \in f(K)?$ It might be something simple (I'm guessing this has nothing to do with the continuity of $f$) but it is completely  eluding me. Thanks!**

Comment: $x \in K$ then $f(x) \in f(K)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of $f(K)$ is the set of images of points in $K$ under $f$, i.e.
$$f(K) := \{f(y) : y \in K\}.$$
Therefore, because $x \in K$, we have $f(x) \in f(K)$ by definition.